# Accuracy problems in estimating pi using Machin's method

Tags: python-3.x, math

I need to estimate pi to 100 decimal places using Machin's method which is as follows. 4(4(arctan(1/5)) - arctan(1/239)) = pi.

This formula is known to converge to pi pretty quickly, with sources citing accuracy of 72 places after the decimal in 50 iterations/terms.

I can only achieve accuracy up to 15 places after the decimal point, using Machin's formula, and I can not figure out why.

I have written a function for the Taylor series of arctan(x) and then I use that function inside another function that applies the formula I have written above. I have also tried setting higher precision using the Decimals module.

```
##This is the function for the taylor series of arctan(x)
def arctan(first_term, terms):
    k = 0
    array = []
    if k < 1:
        x = (((-1)**k)*(first_term)**((2*k)+1))/((2*k)+1)
        k = 1
        array.append(x)
    if k > 0:
        while k < terms:
            x = x + (((-1)**k)*(first_term)**((2*k)+1))/((2*k)+1)
            k += 1
            array.append(x)
        return array[-1]
##Here is the function for Machin's formula
def machinpi(first_term, first_term2, terms):
    x = 4*(arctan(first_term, terms))-(arctan(first_term2, terms))
    return x*4
```

Machin is famous for estimating pi to 100 decimal places by hand. I am trying to figure out how many terms of the series are required to achieve this accuracy. However, I can not find the answer if I can not first converge to 100 decimal places of pi. Using Machin's formula I expect to converge to 72 values after the decimal place in 50 iterations.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using a number type capable of representing 100 digits.

Comment: This is what I was suspecting. I am relatively new to python. When I call the function I use Decimal to wrap the values. For example machinpi(Decimal(1/5), Decimal(1/239), terms), and I set the precision of the decimal to 100. But it seems that that is not correct. What number type should I be using?

Answer (score 3):

Okay I have figured this problem out. I don't know why this happens in python but calling the function I wrote like this machinpi(Decimal(1/5), Decimal(1/239), terms) is not equal to this which has the accuracy that I expect machinpi(Decimal(1)/Decimal(5), Decimal(1)/Decimal(239), terms)

Comment: In Python, arguments of a function are always [evaluated before the function is called](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order). So `Decimal(1/5)` evaluates `1/5` *as a float* and then passes that float (which is not exactly 0.2) to `Decimal`.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for this information, it will definitely come in handy for the future.